# My contract shows a zero balance on Metamask

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, metamask

I just need some help on a contract I'm doing an experimental project token for.

My setup as follows:

Using Remix for solidity
Metamask account linked Contract is using
pragma ^0.4.4 (original code version of this contract) Contract
deployed to Ropsten test network via Metamask

Ive copied an existing contract (ConsenSys token) and added my own features and supply
Solidity remixes the contract and accepts it and I've deployed it.

I've "cut & Paste contract "link" to Metamask - under the "add custom token" option
but it shows a 0 (Nil) balance (have tried a few different contract variants & decimals options
all resulting in 0 balances on Metamask??)

My decimal range is set to 0
so there should be no problem with it reading the total token supply as a whole value?
[image]

I've checked on the contract itself in remix to see it deployed the correct decimal and also correct
supply - both seem fine (see attached)

[image]

Metamask shows "zero" balance
and also when I check the contact on Etherscan tab from the Metamask tab
it shows the contract with an 18 decimal placement?

[image]

So I'm a little stuck on this - and could use some advice on how to get Metamask to read the correct token value.

Comment: I think decimal should not be 0... your total supply has 11 decimals

Comment: there are no decimals (`.`) in `totalSupply` though. what do you mean

Comment: Thanks for your replies. If I want to have a total token supply of lets say 10,000,000 tokens, how would I represent that in the contract?   and How would I also make a decimal value show this?

Comment: User610620, I see actually, you were replying to Majd TLs post. - but I will leave my reply up so everyone understands roughly what I was trying to achieve.